# IONIC2 how i reload page

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

In Ionic2 Page when i'm refreshing the page through `location.reload()` method,and check the application in android device,  the page is displaying with 4-5 second blank white page and then `location.reload()` method is working. How can i solve this issue? Can anyone suggest me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got a very lazy solution, but it works for me:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Loader

import { LoadingController, Loading} from 'ionic-angular';

showLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }

So that user will feel data is loading.

Comment: but it  getting time for perform this  task,as there any other solution?

Comment: As per my understanding it is best.